# Sending people to lunch together with minimal repetition

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, optimization

We have *n* people and split them up in groups of size *x*. Each group of *x* people goes to lunch together. Next time around when the groups are set up people who were in a group last time should not end up in a group together if avoidable. Ideally they also should go out with as few people from the time before that.

I thought about modelling this as a graph problem:
People are vertices $v \in V$ and going to lunch together creates a edge between those vertices. The edge has a weight on it that's higher the more recent the lunch happened. Now we want to create $\frac{|V|}{x}$ subgraphs with *x* vertices each and minimize the sum of the edges connecting the vertices in each subgraph.

Is there a name (*lunching programmers* ? ;-) ) and associated research for this problem? Or is there a way to map this to another known problem?

Comment: You might want to read about block designs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design

Comment: Your problem seems to be a more complicated variant of what is called the "Oberwolfach problem".

Answer (score 3):

This is sometimes known as the [Social Golfer](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sello/golf.html) problem (see also [the Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html) and [this page from CSPlib](http://www.csplib.org/prob/prob010/index.html)). Probably the most famous instance of this problem is [Kirkman's Schoolgirl problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem).